# Drawing to p5.Image instead of to canvas

Tags: processing, p5.js

Given a loaded png image as a template, I want to enable a user to trace elements of the image. In p5, this is easy:

```javascript
setup() {
    // Load image
    var img = loadImage('...');
    image(img, 0, 0);
}

draw() {
    ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 2, 2);
}
```

However, I want to then be able to save *only* the ellipses (without the underlying image). Is there a way to write to an `Image` instead of directly down to the canvas, so that I can lift the pixels of the trace without taking the original image with it?

My current plans are one of:

- Overlay a second p5 instance, and draw on a transparent canvas overlaid on the image... But this seems harder to maintain, and may suffer from the DOM being out of perfect alignment
- Instead of using `ellipse`, write to a `createImage`-generated pixel array... But this seems slow and unpleasant.

Caveat: The image is a `p5.Image`, so overlaying on top of a `<img>` won't be enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`createGraphics()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createGraphics) function to create an instance of `p5.Renderer`. You can then draw to the `p5.Renderer` and then overlay it on top of the image. Then you can access the pixel array of the `p5.Renderer` to get just the overlay, not the image.

Here is an example:

```js
var img;
    var pg;
    
    function preload() {
      img = loadImage("https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/06ce4c0f7ee07cf79c81ac6602f5d502?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG");
    }
    
    function setup(){
      createCanvas(300, 600);
      pg = createGraphics(300, 300);
    }
    
    function mousePressed(){
      pg.fill(255, 0, 0);
      pg.ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 20, 20);
    }
    
    function draw() {
      image(img, 0, 0, 300, 300);
      image(pg, 0, 0);
      image(pg, 0, 300);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.0/p5.js"></script>
Click in the image to draw to the buffer below it! (View as full page to see the buffer.)
```

[image: drawing to image overlay]

More info can be found in [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createGraphics).

By the way there is a [p5.js](/questions/tagged/p5.js) tag.

Comment: Aha — the period in the middle is what got me. Thank for the edit, btw!

Comment: @j6m8 No problem. I've edited my example to more closely align with your requirements. Now it loads an image, creates an overlay, draws to the overlay, and then draws the overlay on top of the image as well as under the image. Sounds like a fun project, good luck!